# How to construct a PythonTuple from C#

Tags: ironpython

I want to construct an IronPython tuple from C#. These are PythonTuple's public constructors:

```
    public PythonTuple();
    public PythonTuple(object o);
```

How would I construct, for example, the tuple (1, 2, 3)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually give the object constructor any enumerable object.  This could be an `ArrayList`, a `List<object>`, a `List<string>`, a `PythonDictionary`, a `HashSet`, a string, a byte array.  Whatever you want - if you can enumerate it in IronPython then you can give it to the constructor.

So for example you could do:

```
new PythonTuple(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on a mailing list somewhere:

```
PythonTuple myTuple = PythonOps.MakeTuple(new object[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use the `PythonTuple(object)` constructor with an `IronPython.Runtime.List`:

```
// IronPython.Runtime.List
List list = new List();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);

PythonTuple tuple = new PythonTuple(list);

foreach (int i in tuple)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tuple item: {0}", i);
}
```